# ios Swift - Synchronize UISegmentedControl to UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uipageviewcontroller

Is there a way to synchronize the segmented control to UIPageViewController and animate the tranzition?

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492329/smooth-transition-with-uipageviewcontroller-and-uisegmentedcontrol-like-in-apple